# convert all lowercase letters to uppercase letters and vice versa

Tags: python, python-3.x, swap

i am trying to learn python, given a string I want to swap cases.

this problem wants some inputs for me to complete this exercise

```
def swap_case():
return:
    swap_case = s.swapcase
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = input()
    result = swap_case(s)
    print(result)
```

Comment: The problem is a syntax error because `return: swap_case = s.swapcase` is not valid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
def swap_case(s):
  return s.swapcase()

if __name__ == '__main__':

 s = input()
 result = swap_case(s)
 print(result)
```